# Does accessing array elements by index take longer if the indices are further apart?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

Does something like

```
Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
Console.WriteLine(arr[1]);
```

take shorter than

```
Console.WriteLine(arr[0]);
Console.WriteLine(arr[1823]);
```

for hardware-level reasons?

Comment: In the general case no. But there are nuances related to the cache.

Comment: In most cases yes. Say array contains integers, and first element is not in any CPU cache and should be fetched from main memory. It will not be fetched alone, it's just 4 bytes and it would be not efficient to fetch just those 4 bytes. Instead, a larger chunk of continuous memory is fetched and cached in CPU. Now when in next line you access second element - chances are high it's now in CPU cache and main memory need not be bothered. Fetching from cache is much faster than from memory. If you next access 1823th element - it's unlikely to be in cache and another trip to memory is needed.

Comment: I disagree with EVK.  Memory is memory and shouldn't make a difference if it is main memory or cache.  The microprocessor has sectors and as long as the memory sector is valid is should make a difference.  the microprocessors these days can access a memory location using a sector and address (64 bits) and can get an location in one fetch.  Any offsets (up to 64 bits) can also be added in one microprocessor instruction.  It will take longer if you are dealing with huge memory where the sizes are larger than 64 bits.

Comment: It's even more complex than Evk says. For instance, suppose that your algo reads the entire array, but just in random order. If the entire array fits in cache then you will still have the same amount of main memory reads as if you read the array sequentially, and so the time taken will be the same. Your question can't really be answered in isolation.

Answer (score -1):

Accessing array elements is more or less O(1). That's because, when you do `myIntArray[500]`, you're really doing something like: `memory_location + 500 * sizeof(int)`.

Now, technically, larger numbers take longer to multiply, but that difference is incredibly small, so we can just call it O(1), so the difference in your example probably won't ever be felt.

Comment: This is too simplistic. Interaction between main memory and cache is what drives actual performance.

Comment: This is what I've found out from searching it.

Comment: What is what you've found out? Your answer, or my comment?

Comment: My answer, via a few StackOverflow questions.

Comment: I'm afraid that what you think you have found out is not correct.